# rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' * doesn't work on windows subsystem for linux (wsl)

Tags: windows, filenames, rename, windows-subsystem-for-linux, case-sensitivity

When you do it it says file already exists.

example output:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

```
Totemic-1.12.2-0.11.6.jar not renamed: totemic-1.12.2-0.11.6.jar already exists
TreeChoppin-1.12.2-1.0.0.jar not renamed: treechoppin-1.12.2-1.0.0.jar already exists
UniDict-1.12.2-2.9.3.jar not renamed: unidict-1.12.2-2.9.3.jar already exists
VanillaFix-1.0.10-99.jar not renamed: vanillafix-1.0.10-99.jar already exists
WailaHarvestability-mc1.12-1.1.12.jar not renamed: wailaharvestability-mc1.12-1.1.12.jar already exists
WanionLib-1.12.2-2.4.jar not renamed: wanionlib-1.12.2-2.4.jar already exists
```

How do I make this work with wsl? it works flawlessly on my Ubuntu systems.

Comment: This is probably because windows file systems are case insensitive.  `FOO.txt` is the same file as `foo.txt` as far as it's concerned.  You will probably have to move the files to another name temporarily before moving them back.

Comment: You need to identify the (part of the) filesystem you're running that on, and also the version. In general files under `/mnt/c` (i.e. Windows files) will be case-insensitive and those elsewhere will not on recent versions. You can [edit] your question with more information.

Comment: @Jesse_b thank you for that, i had forgotten about.

Comment: @MichaelHomer yes it's in the windows files and you're right, it's case insensitive and makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this has something to do with case-insensitive filenames, so if `rename` checks if the target file exists, it sees the original and stops to avoid destroying it.

The Perl rename  on my system has this option which looks like it could work here:

```
-f, -force
           Over write: allow existing files to be over-written.
```

Even if that didn't work, you should be able to rename the files to something that's not just a case alteration. E.g. add an `x` to the beginning while changing case, and then remove that `x`:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/^/x/' *
rename 's/^x//' *
```

(of course that won't work if you have files called `foo` and `xfoo`, but you can always change the prefix to something else.)

Comment: Excellent I tested with two rename commands and it worked. this is a good solution. Thank you very much.

Tried the `-f` option and that had no effect other than to not kick back error messages. Feel free to edit your answer. Also, I'm choosing this answer.

thanks Again.